# Linked list nodes- Having trouble displaying my output for my card game

Tags: java

Were learning about Linked list nodes in class with Push pop, and peek. The premise of the program is to show the players cards that they have and who won. The program has different objects For the winning deck and each players hand.

The Following is a For Else loop to display the winner:

```
for(int i= 0; i<26; i++)
    if(p1cards.peek() > p2cards.peek()) {
        p1cardsWon.push(p1cards.peek());
        System.out.println("Player 1 won: " + p1cardsWon);
        p1cards.pop();
    } else if (p2cards.peek() > p1cards.peek()) {
        p2cardsWon.push(p2cards.peek());
        System.out.println("Player 2 won: " + p2cardsWon);
        p2cards.pop();
    }
```

And here is my Push, Pop and Peek Methods:

```
public void push(T item) {
    if (head == null) {
        // The stack is empty
        Node newNode = new Node(item, null);
        head = newNode;
    } else {
        // Stack is not empty, create a new node at the top of the stack
        // The new item's next link goes to the "old" head
        Node newNode = new Node(item, head);
        // Now we can re-assign the link to the new head
        head = newNode;
    }
}

public T pop() {

    T top = peek();
    if (head!= null)
        head = head.getNext();

    return top;
}

public T peek() {
    T top = null;

    if (!isEmpty())
        top=head.getData();

    return top;
}
```

And Finally here is my toString method:

```
public String toString() {
    String retStr = "Contents:\n";
    Node current = head;
    while(current != null) {
        retStr += current.getData() + "\n";
        current = current.getNext();
    }
    return retStr;
}
```

The output that I got [looks like this](https://gist.github.com/glorksnork/661f64b478c4ee10f5f6b878e969c265)

I've been trying to figure out if it's one of my methods or my For Else loop. Thank you in advance.

also [here are my classes](https://gist.github.com/glorksnork/c067c20f6cf7d9acb1cacde34e5b500d) for the Card game and the methods

Comment: In your `pop()` method, why are you throwing an `EmptyStackException` when the stack is not empty?  Shouldn't you be throwing that if the stack **is** empty?

Comment: Ok that makes sense I changed it up a bit and changed my outcome for what I have now @Jordan

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're kind of mixing multiple ways of doing the same thing.  You have `Node` objects that keep track of data plus a `next`.  However, you're also using a `stack` array for your `peek()` method, but nothing ever adds anything to `stack`.

Did you intend to remove the array behavior in favor of a linked list, and forget to update your `peek()` method?

Comment: Oh a fellow student actually gave me that. How would you right it?

Comment: This is where things get a bit iffy for me.  I'm fine helping people understand programming concepts, but I'm not going to flat-out write anyone's code.  Especially when you're not even the author of the code that you're having issues with.  One thing that I absolutely **won't** do is facilitate academic dishonesty.  So instead, I'll direct you to look at the `push()`  and `pop()` methods, try to understand what they're doing, and attempt to make the `peek()` method use the same mechanism.  If you have issues with that, post your updated code and we can go from there.

Comment: ok I changed both methods a bit and added a link to my outcome. What would I change to my For Else loop that would help me display only one winner

Comment: Before we get to that, you still have some of the old, not-linked-list code in there.  Try completely removing `stack` and `topIndex`, since they're not used at all for the LinkedList implementation.  Your code will break.  Then you'll have to do some work to get it to compile again, keeping in mind that everything is will be based on `head` being the top of your stack.

Comment: I'm a little confused where is it?

Comment: In your `LinkedStack` class, you have several variables at the top:  head, stack, topIndex, and DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY.  If you're doing this with a linked list instead of an array (and it sounds like that's how you were asked to implement this), then the only one of those that you need is `head`.  You should delete the rest.  That'll cause a lot of your code to break, because that code was doing things the wrong way (with the old array-based implementation, and not with the new stack-based implementation).  So your next task will be to rewrite the broken parts to work with a linked list.